# replacing a char in line by output of who using SED giving error

Tags: bash

Im trying to **replace** the letter **I** in the 5th line by output of **who** command but getting an error

*sed: -e expression #1, char 49: unterminated `s' command*

I have tried using **eval** with no success

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7
do
    mkdir $1/$i
    cp hello.txt $1/$i
    user=$(who)
    sed -i '5 s/.*/I changed this line/' $1/$i/hello.txt
    sed -i "5 s/I/$(who)/" $1/$i/hello.txt
done
```

Comment: If the output of `who` contains the separator used for the `sed` command (`/` here) it would explain the problem. If that's the case, change the separator for one you can't find in the output of `who`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide us with a [mcve] - at the moment, there are too many things that are unknown to us, which makes it difficult for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Aaron i wanted who but yes the seperator(/ here) is the problem

Comment: That's because the output of `who` contains characters that have a special meaning in the `s` command. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `who` well, but a quick test reveals that it can contain `/` characters, which is the delimiter you used for your `sed` command. On my system, it did output something along the line of :

```
myName   pts/0        2016-09-07 11:14 (10.123.45.678)
```

Notice the `/` in `pts/0` , that's what's breaking the `sed` command, since it's its delimiter. Indeed, the following expanded `sed` command contains a `/` too many :

```
sed -i "5 s/I/myName   pts/0        2016-09-07 11:14 (10.123.45.678)/" $1/$i/hello.txt
```

I think you could solve your problem by using the `whoami` command instead, whose output probably correspond much better to what you expect:

```
$ whoami
myName
```

If you do want to use the output of `who`, you will have either to escape the delimiter in the output of the `who` command, or to use a delimiter that cannot be output by `who`.

Assuming that `who` will never output any `+` character (I don't know if it's true, you should make sure !), you could use the following `sed` command instead, where `+` is used as a delimiter :

```
sed -i "5 s+I+$(who)+" $1/$i/hello.txt
```

Comment: Note that I'm not sure there's any perfect solution : if I'm not mistaken, unix usernames can now contain any character but the `NUL` character, and I'm pretty sure we can't use `NUL` as a sed delimiter. That means an username could contain the `sed` delimiter you'd pick and break that code. That affects both the `who` and `whoami` solutions. If someone can expand on that I'd be very interested to hear about it :)

Comment: I replaced / by + in the second sed command yet I don't get the desired output

Comment: what's the desired output? what do you get?

Comment: Desired output as in the output of who in place of I

Comment: So, for example "myName   pts/0        2016-09-07 11:14 (10.123.45.678) changed this line" ? And what did you get instead?

Comment: Yes like you said / is the problem, I verified it using a variable which does not contain /

Comment: $(who) changed this line

Comment: Thanks. Have you switched from double quotes to single quotes? that would explain the problem. `echo "I am the best" | sed "s+I am+$(who) is+"` works just fine